# IntelliJ IDEA: Where is "reformat on commit" stored?

Tags: intellij-idea

We have a complex project where we version control a clean version of our project files, which is locally exported to each checkout by a setup script.

We are now talking about using "reformat on commit", so I'm looking into putting this into our project files, but I can't find where it puts the data.

When I commit with "reformat on commit", IntelliJ remembers that selection for the next commit. It remembers this across restarts, but not between projects. Hence, I'm assuming that it's a project setting, not a global IDE preference.

But where is it?

-edit- We're using file based (.ipr), not directory based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in `.idea/workspace.xml`:

```xml
<component name="VcsManagerConfiguration">
    <option name="REFORMAT_BEFORE_PROJECT_COMMIT" value="true" />
</component>
```

Comment: We're using file based projects, not folder based, so there is no .idea directory

Comment: Your comment helped me find it though based on being able to search for the correct keywords, it was in the iws file. Thank you very much :)